# How can I make some portion of TempData text bold?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, razorengine

How can I make some portion of TempData text bold?

```
TempData["message"] = $"<span class=\"font-weight-bold\">{vm.Customer}</span> saved";
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
alert('@Html.Raw(TempData["message"])')
```